# Convert excel to pdf in landscape orientation

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, pdf

I am trying to convert an excel table to pdf which works with the following code:

```
    xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('Table.xlsx')
    ws = books.Worksheets[0]
    ws.Visible = 1
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, 'Table.pdf')
    books.Save()
    books.Close()
```

The only issue is that I need the table to be in landscape orientation and I am at a loss as to how to make that specification.

I have seen solutions with code such as `ws.PageSetup.Orientation = xlLandscape` or some variation of that, but I believe this only works in VBA/ I am unable to find the correct syntax for python.

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to hack together some code which does what I had originally asked. I am certain there is a better way to go about this, but for anyone stuck on the same issue, this might help.

I ended up "saving as" the existing .xlsx file as a new macro enabled excel file and entering a macro created in python. The VBA code makes it possible to change the file into landscape mode and then export as a PDF. Once the macro runs through, I delete the .xlsm file. The try statement at the end prevents an error from occuring if the excel application did not close yet.

```
# Save as pdf
# Start excel application
xlApp = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
# Open the table previously created
books = xlApp.Workbooks.Open('Table.xlsx'))

# xlmodule allows for insertion of VBA code which we will use to change orientation and save as pdf
xlmodule = books.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(1)
# VBACode is the VBA code used, sub ... is the name of the macro
VBACode = '''Sub PDF_Creation()
        With Worksheets("Overlap Matrix").PageSetup
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
        End With

        Worksheets("Overlap Matrix").ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:="C:/.../PDF_test.pdf", _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=True
        End Sub'''
# Now we add the VBA code as a macro to the excel sheet
xlmodule.CodeModule.AddFromString(VBACode)

# To use the VBA code we must first save the file as xlsm -> FileFormat 52 denotes xlsm
books.SaveAs('Table', FileFormat=52)
# Close the book so that we can reopen it as a macro enabled file
books.Close()

# Open the newly created xlsm file
xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename='Table.xlsm', ReadOnly=1)
# Run the macro
xlApp.Application.Run('Table.xlsm!PDF_Creation')

# Quit the application
xlApp.Application.Quit()
# Delete the macro file, we still have the file without macros as a backup
# Use while loop to continue trying till we actually quit the excel application
file_deleted = False
while file_deleted is False:
    try:
        os.remove('Table.xlsm')
        file_deleted = True
    except WindowsError:
        sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

An easier approach would be to change the orientation before printing:

```
def print_excel_worksheet_to_pdf(i_sz_excel_path, i_sz_ws_name, i_sz_pdf_path):
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

excel.Visible = False   #Keep the excel sheet closed
excel.DisplayAlerts = False  #"Do you want to over write it?" Will not Pop up

try:
    wb_source = excel.Workbooks.Open(i_sz_excel_path)

    ws_source = wb_source.Worksheets(i_sz_ws_name)
    ws_source.PageSetup.Orientation = 2 # change orientation to landscape
    ws_source.Select()

    wb_source.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, i_sz_pdf_path)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

excel.Application.Quit()
```

As long as you don't save your changes this doesn't affect the original file, and removes the need for temporary files with vbscript macros